# Running a macOS service for open with emacs failed with "emacsclient: could not get terminal name mac"

Tags: macos, emacs

I created a service in macOS so I could open any file with emacs as I wanted. The service was created using Automator with the following shell script:

`/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/emacs/25.3/bin/emacsclient -nc "$@"`

While this service will always failed with the following message:

`emacsclient: could not get terminal name`

Anyone has some clues? Thanks forward.

Comment: I was able to make this work under Automator using your command line without any special settings, loading a file into a running Emacs.app successfully. But I build my own Emacs.app rather than using homebrew, so there could well be a difference there. You might try passing the `--display ns` option to tell it to use the Mac windowing system, assuming you're not running your emacs in a terminal.

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution and it works for me. Another workaround is `open -a Emacs “$@“`