# Opening emacsclient in terminal works but won't work with Automator

Tags: emacs, terminal, automator, spacemacs, emacsclient

So I'm getting some pretty strange behaviour when I try to use an Automator service to open new emacs (GNU Version 25.2 with spacemacs) buffers.

In my terminal, the command `emacsclient -a '' -c` works as expected, opening a new buffer through emacsclient. However, when I make a service in Automator which simply runs a (`/bin/bash`)  shell script:

`emacsclient -a '' -c`

I get an error message: 

`The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “emacsclient: could not get terminal name”`

On suspicions that this was due to Automator not using some default `PATH` variable, I tried the following instead:

`PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH 
emacsclient -c`

which produced the same error as before.

Next I tried 

`PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin export PATH;
emacsclient -c`

which produced a **different** error message:

`` The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “emacsclient: invalid option -- c
Try `emacsclient --help' for more information” ``

however why I try that script in my terminal it also gives a similar error which doesn't make much sense to me.

If anyone has suggestions for how to fix this I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the shell script is running an old version of emacsclient in /usr/bin you need to run the one in Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient. Delete the PATH line and you can use a solution listed here for running emacsclient inside automator [Running a macOS service for open with emacs failed with "emacsclient: could not get terminal name mac"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46618983/running-a-macos-service-for-open-with-emacs-failed-with-emacsclient-could-not)